# '68–95–99.7 rule' equivalent for multivariate normal distribution

Tags: standard-deviation, cumulative-distribution-function, multivariate-normal-distribution, rule-of-thumb

The [68–95–99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) is a convenient way of quickly getting an overview of the spread of some normally distributed data.

**I am wondering if there is an equivalent rule in the multivariate case?** and how would I go about proving/disproving this?

Comment: I guess you would like to use chisquared distribution with the corresponding quantiles, like qchisq(c(0.68, 0.95, 0.997), df). For 2 normals you will have: 2.278869;  5.991465; 11.618286. You can prove it using definition of chi squared distribution. Of course you will need to standartize your data before and use the covariance matrix if your RVs are not independent. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ClHmC.png

Comment: If your question was more clearly formulated it would be more clearly a duplicate. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149334/multivariate-standard-deviation/149346#149346) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092/bottom-to-top-explanation-of-the-mahalanobis-distance/62147#62147) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69350/about-trivariate-normal-distribution/69358#69358) for some discussion of relevant concepts and calculations. If you can formulate a clear question that is not covered by these, please post a new question.

Comment: Also see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67422/volume-of-the-95-confidence-ellipsoid/67429#67429)